# Can I mimic a matrix report with a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, reporting

I'd like to show something like a matrix report in a Visualforce page. The horizontal axis is date; the vertical is site(or location)*.  The displayed value is a ratio based on attendance.  Not every site operates every day, so there will be gaps.  Also, some sites open/close on different dates.  The data is currently stored in an object that represents one site/day pair.

Can this data be displayed as a table in a Visualforce page?  Or will it be necessary to create another type of object where the object represents an entire row (or column?).

*these could be switch if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Really anything is possible, it's just a question of how much time you want to dedicate to it. This question isn't really appropriate for SFSE, which is intended for help with specific problems in code/configuration.

Comment: It can be done. Think in terms of wrapper classes.

Comment: Yes the crux of your problem is in the Model layer of MVC. The rest should fall into place once you nail that down.

Comment: @jagular why not run a report on the object and use reporting API to display the output on a VF page?

Comment: I will look into this.  I was thinking I would use the loading of the VF page to delete and recreate the objects in question.  They mirror another object's data.  Our trigger situation is currently too complex to permit the use of triggers for the update.